# Django, update user profile with password confirmation

Tags: python, django, django-forms

So, I want to let my user edit his profile.

User has username, email and picture.

Additionally I want user to confirm his password when he edits his profile and that's where my problem is.

It looks like that

[image]

Instead of checking my password and update username and/or email and/or picture my program updates everything. Plus password is broken after update.

forms.py

```
class UpdateProfile(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^\w+$', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=dict(required=True, max_length=30)),
                                label=_("Username"), error_messages={
            'invalid': _("This value must contain only letters, numbers and underscores.")})
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=dict(required=True, max_length=30)), label=_("Email address"))
    password = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs=dict(required=True, max_length=30, render_value=False)), label=_("Password"))
    picture = forms.ImageField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password', 'picture')

    def clean_username(self):
        if self.initial['username'] == self.cleaned_data['username']:
            return self.cleaned_data['username']
        try:
            user = Person.objects.get(username__iexact=self.cleaned_data['username'])
        except Person.DoesNotExist:
            return self.cleaned_data['username']
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("The username already exists. Please try another one."))

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        if self.initial['email'] == email:
            return email
        try:
            gg = Person.objects.get(email=email)
        except Person.DoesNotExist:
            return email
        print("DUPLICATE")
        raise forms.ValidationError('duplicate email')

    def clean(self):
        if 'password' in self.cleaned_data :
            p =Person.objects.get(username__iexact=self.initial['username'])
            if not p.check_password(self.cleaned_data['password']):
                raise forms.ValidationError(_("Password is wrong."))
        return self.cleaned_data
```

views.py

```
def edit(request):
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UpdateProfile(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=Person.objects.get_by_natural_key(request.user.get_username()))
        args['user_form'] = user_form
        if user_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
    args['user_form'] = UpdateProfile(request.POST or None)
    args['user2'] = Person.objects.get_by_natural_key(request.user.get_username())
    return render_to_response('edit.html', args, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

In html I have default form.

I think that problem is that I have password field in `UpdateProfile`. However, I don't know how to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'picture')
```

I deleted password from fields and now it's working. I don't know if it is proper solution of my problem, but it works.